# Solr - using _text_ catch-all field

Tags: solr

I am trying to index a sample JSON document in my Solr core which is as follows

```
[
  {
    "ID": "1",
    "title": "Cooking Recommendations",
    "tags": ["cooking", "meetup"],
    "posts": [{
        "ID": "2",
        "title": "Cookies",
        "comments": [{
            "ID": "3",
            "content": "Lovely recipe"
          },
          {
            "ID": "4",
            "content": "A-"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ID": "5",
        "title": "Cakes"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ID": "6",
    "title": "For Hire",
    "tags": ["professional", "jobs"],
    "posts": [{
        "ID": "7",
        "title": "Search Engineer",
        "comments": [{
           "ID": "8",
           "content": "I am interested"
         },
         {
           "ID": "9",
           "content": "How large is the team?"
         }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ID": "10",
        "title": "Low level Engineer"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now, I have updated my `managed-schema.xml` file to enable the `_text_` catch-all field as I would want to make free-text queries without specifying the key against which the query string should be run.

This is how my schema looks

```
<field name="_root_" type="text_general" indexed="false" stored="true" docValues="false" />
<field name="_nest_path_" type="_nest_path_" />
<fieldType name="_nest_path_" class="solr.NestPathField" />

<field name="_text_" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<copyField source="*" dest="_text_"/>
```

The corresponding analyzer

```
    <fieldType name="_text_" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1" />
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />              
            <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="German" />
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1" />
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />              
            <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="German" />
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

With this config, the JSON documents gets indexed fine and I am able to run a query like `title:"Cooking Recommendations"` to retrieve the first JSON object alone. However, I am trying to run a free-text query without specifying the key `title` and just pass the query string to fetch the same results. I looked into the Solr documentation and see that I can achieve this with `CopyField` directive, however, if I just pass the string "Cooking Recommendations", I get no results.

I did see the core's schema and see that `_text_` field is available. Not sure what I am missing here. Can someone guide me?

**EDIT:**

I am performing my queries using the Solr query UI which is as follows:

[image: Solr query UI]

I am using `/select` as the request handler, passing the df as `_text_`. Still, it doesn't return the results I expect.

**EDIT 2:**

I tried using the Analysis tab as suggested below and see that it works fine there.

[image: Solr Analysis tab]

Comment: mention the default search field in your schema and try

Comment: The <defaultSearchField> is used by Solr when parsing queries to identify which field name should be searched in queries where an explicit field name has not been used.

Comment: if you are using the latest version (above 7)then It's recommended to use df parameter.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. Yeah I do use the df field. Will update my question.

Comment: did you tried in the solr analysis page...is it matching there?

Comment: Yeah I did. It returns fine there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to make this work. All I had to do was to remove the analyzer for `_text_` and let Solr handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `solrconfig.xml` file that comes with Solr, you will see that the `/select requestHandler`.

It is configured with the default search field as below
`<str name="df">name</str>` in the
`<lst name="defaults"> </lst>` tag.

Mark the `requestHandler` which do you want to be used as default using `default="true"`.